# Display file from first step of wizard in another step

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I'm using SessionWizardView with `file_storage = FileSystemStorage(something)`.

For first step there is a form with `image = forms.ImageField()`. In the last step I'd like to display the image (which I get with `self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')`) in the template. I can't use `{{ image.url }}` because it is `UploadedFile` object. What is the proper way to display the image?

Comment: get_context_data might be of use to you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data

Comment: I call `get_cleanded_data_for_step('0')` in `get_context_data`, but I have problem with displaying image I have, because it's `UploadedFile`, not `ImageField`. It has file name, local directory and `File` object.

Comment: Can you show a more complete code example of what you have done?

Comment: I have written everything already. I try to get file in `get_context_data` and pass it to the template. The only way I see is to write in .html base64 file content but I am not satisfied of this method.